# Is it possible to generate input for parametrize?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a rather large set of parameters to run through several test cases.
I'd prefer to have the set live somewhere else rather than in the parametrize statement, poplulating the parametrize, if possible. This way parametrizing several test case doesn't have duplicate large blocks of test case parameters.

If that is not possible is there another way to "share" this parametrization? To avoid having duplicates decorate the affected test cases?

```
import pytest

# this data structure has about 20 of these
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c" [('hello' [(1,1), ('abc','abc')],[(1, 2)]....)
def test_case_a(a, b, c):

# the same data and arguments as test_case_a
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c" [('hello' [(1,1), ('abc','abc')],[(1, 2)]....)
def test_case_b(a, b, c):
```

Comment: Show code please and provide a working example.

Comment: This is an organization and efficiency question. I can have the code working with parametrize and a gigantic block repeated several times throughout the module, but I would prefer not. I have posted a small example to illustrate what I have asked in word format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your shared params in a global variable:

**test.py**

```
import pytest

SHARED_PARAMS = "a, b, c", [['hello', [(1, 1), ('abc', 'abc')], [(1, 2)]]]

@pytest.mark.parametrize(*SHARED_PARAMS)
def test_case_a(a, b, c):
    pass

@pytest.mark.parametrize(*SHARED_PARAMS)
def test_case_b(a, b, c):
    pass
```

**Execution results:**

```
$ pytest -v
=========================== test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.0, pytest-3.6.2, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.6.0 
-- /home/user/.virtualenvs/test3.7/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/user/projects/so, inifile:
collected 2 items

so/test_api.py::test_case_a[hello-b0-c0] PASSED
so/test_api.py::test_case_b[hello-b0-c0] PASSED

======================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =======================
```